# Using JPA mapped by not primary key field?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I am having troubles getting this working and I wonder if what I am doing simply does not make sense?

```
public class Application {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;
    ....
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Sample {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne (cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    protected Application application;
    ....
}

// TestSample contains a list that is mapped not by the primary key of the Sample
public class TestSample extends Sample {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="application", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Part> parts = new ArrayList<Part>();
    ....
}

public class Part {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id = 0;

    @ManyToOne (cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    Application application;
}
```

The problem I am having is that I am able to add parts, the database looks correct, then when I attempt to fetch the the `parts` list I get an empty list.

I can get it to work if I compromise on the database structure by changing these classes:

```
// TestSample contains a list that is mapped not by the primary key of the Sample
public class TestSample extends Sample {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="testSample", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Part> parts = new ArrayList<Part>();
    ....
}

public class Part {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id = 0;

    @ManyToOne (cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    TestSample testSample;
}
```

The tables are being auto generated by hibernate, so they are coming out like this:

```
application
  id : number
  ....

test_sample
  id : number
  application_id : number
  ...

part
  id : number
  application_id : number
```

If I change it to the less desirable way that works, the last table is different:

```
part
  id : number
  test_sample_id : number
```

Because the id's in all cases are being auto generated, there are no shared primary keys. Essentially what I am trying to do is use mappedby where mappedby is referring to a field that is not the primary key of the table/class called "TestSample". This is what I am not sure if makes sense in JPA.

Comment: I don't understand your mapping (you have a OneToOne on one side and and OneToMany on the other side). And how is the foreign key defined if not on the PK? Can you show your tables?

Comment: I have added the final class, hopefully this clears it up. a `TestSample` has `Part`s. However because `TestSample` has a one to one relationship with `Application`, I am using the primary key of Application in the `parts` list.

Comment: The `OneToMany` from `TestSample` isn't bidirectional, why does it have a `mappedBy`? Also, please show the tables and constraints, I'd like to understand how this is supposed to work (are you using a shared primary key between `Application` and `Sample`?)

Comment: The OneToMany is bi-directional with the "Part" class. I think this is getting very difficult to explain (:

Answer (score 0):

> The OneToMany is bi-directional with the "Part" class. I think this is getting very difficult to explain (:

Your one-to-many association between `TestSample` and `Part` is **not** bidirectional, the `mappedBy` is not correct (the `application` table is **not** owning the relation, it is not even aware of `test_sample`), your mapping doesn't make sense. There is something to change.

I think that you should show what the **expected** tables are, not the generated one (since the mappings are incoherent, the generated result can't be satisfying). You are talking about compromise so I believe that you have an idea of what the expected result should be. Please show it.